How to control/filter the message sent to log4net.Level.Debug for different appender
My message for log.Debug('Hello Piyush') ;
I have 2 appender in log4net.Config.Xml file
FileAppender and ConsoleAppender.
So for fileappender i want to log Hello Piyush however for ConsoleAppender only Hello.
So to do this, how we can filer/ control the message?
